# Django was installed but fail to import

Tags: python, django

I have installed Django,but cannot execute `manage.py`

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z forum]# python manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Django exists there

```
In [1]: import django
In [2]: django
Out[2]: <module 'django' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py'>
In [3]: django.__file__
Out[3]: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py'
```

Comment: Are you sure that in both cases they are the same python?

Comment: oh, thank you. could you please transmit the succinct comment to answer. @eyllanesc

Comment: One of the most common mistakes of beginners is not realize that they have several python installed, and install the package in one of them and try with the other generating such errors. execute `python3 manage.py shell`